# django.core.signing unicode error

Tags: python, django, unicode

When i try to unsign a non-unicode string django throws the `DjangoUnicodeDecodeError`. Basically, I try to do something like this:

```
from django.core.signing import Signer

signer = Signer()

signer.unsign(signer.sign(chr(248)))
```

And then I get the following exception:

```
{DjangoUnicodeDecodeError}'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte. You passed in '\xf8' (<type 'str'>)`
```

I tried to use utf-8 encoding, but that didn't help.

Comment: `chr(248)` is not a valid UTF-8 byte. What kind of *actual data* do you have? Your data may be text encoded to a different codec, but there are any number of codecs that use 248 to encode a character.

Comment: the actual data contains some danish words, so I tried to use cp865 and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from django.core.signing import Signer

signer = Signer()

signer.unsign(signer.sign(u'\xf8'))
```

Comment: I have to do it automatically, this is just a simplified example.

Comment: What do you mean with automatically? you would just receive the charcode 248 for example? You could use unichr(248)